# Filling out text in a dropdown field in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC

Tags: adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

I have a form that I'm working on that has several drop down fields for country selection. Unfortunately, my country doesn't appear in the drop down. Is there any way I can change the form from a drop down to a text field so that I can write in my country name?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Reader, and if the dropdown (aka combobox) allows for entering text, you can. Whether this feature is available depends on decisions taken by the creator of the form.

If the dropdown does not allow for entering text, there is nothing you can do.

If you have Acrobat, and the form is not protected against changes, you can get at the dropdown, and either add your own country, or set the option to allow for text entry.

In any case, you should contact the issuer of the form, and complain about the non-capability to select your country.